# SQL Availability Group Listeners in Windows Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, windows-server-2012, high-availability

We have a staging and production SharePoint farm housed within Windows Azure.  All servers run Windows Server 2012.  We're having the same issues in both environments, but for this question, I'll focus on the staging environment.

For the staging environment, I have several servers within the SharePoint farm and 2 SQL servers.  All servers are located on the same subnet and affinity group.  There is a DHCP server that hands out 192.168.X.X addresses for all servers on the subnet.

I've created a WSFC with both SQL servers as nodes.  I've tried creating the cluster with an IP of an unused DHCP address (192.168.X.X) and with a link local address (using a PowerShell script to create the cluster found online from Microsoft).  In both cases, the cluster IP is not accessible from any machine on the subnet.  However, in both cases, the cluster appears to be up and restarting the active node pushes the passive node to the new active node.  I think that this may be one of my root problems.

My final goal is to create an SQL Availability Group Listener for SharePoint to use for DB connections.  With the cluster created, I am able to create an Availability Group in SQL Management Studio.  I can see that it works: when rebooting the primary replica, the secondary turns to primary, all DBs are synced and up to date, etc.  However, when I try to create the AG Listener, it fails with an error claiming that it cannot access the cluster or the cluster is not active.

I've read a lot online.  Some claim that it's not possible to create AGs in Azure, others claim that this hotfix fixes things (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2854082), and a few that claim it works when you set the Listener IP to the public endpoint.  I've tried them all and haven't had any success.  There's got to be some way to increase the reliability of SQL in a totally enclosed, Azure environment.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Has anyone gotten it to work?  If so, how did you do it?  If not, is there another way to go about SQL availability?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you find a solution?